# List of all uris

Tags: http, uri

I would like to save the classification from esco into a file using the uri.

I would like to have skills and competences pillars and words or every level.

I can see in every page that there is the specific uri.

However it is time consuming and possible to not the whole information. Is there any way to find the full list of uris for skills pillar.

example of uri get call

```
https://ec.europa.eu/esco/api/resource/skill?uri=http://data.europa.eu/esco/skill/a59708e3-e654-4e37-8b8a-741c3b756eee&language=en%20HTTP/1.1
```

[Example page](https://ec.europa.eu/esco/portal/skill) with concept uri

Comment: Did you try downloading the ESCO files, e.g. by visiting https://esco.ec.europa.eu/en/use-esco/download?